# Is it possible to see system temperature without entering BIOS?

Tags: cpu, bios, motherboard, desktop-computer, temperature

Is it possible to see the system (not CPU) temperature without entering BIOS? I can see my system temperatures whenever I enter my BIOS, and as I can see CPU and GPU temps in 3rd party apps such as NZXT CAM, I was wondering if I could see the system temps too.

 My specifications:
Motherboard: Gigabyte H610M S2H V2 DDR4 
 CPU: Intel i5-12400F
GPU: Zotac Twin Edge NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Overclocked Edition
Cooler: some corsair AIO
Fans: 3 Noctua fans

Comment: In the BIOS, there is a section that says "system temperature", which I assume is the temperature of the inside of the PC.

Comment: Also what kind of hardware can be used to monitor this?

Comment: no, the cpu temperature is shown above in a section named "CPU Temp.", which is much higher than the system temperature

Comment: @Ramhound Some motherboards do actually have ambient temperature sensors. Probably uncommon outside of servers, but I've heard of it once or twice. Though it's probably more likely to be monitoring the temperature of some other chip (neither CPU nor ambient), like the "chipset" if that's still a thing these days (I haven't kept up with the changes).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738494/get-cpu-temperature-in-cmd-power-shell

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to see the system (not CPU) temperature without entering BIOS?

Yes. [SpeedFan - Access temperature sensor in your computer](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) will do this.

> SpeedFan is a program that monitors voltages, fan speeds and temperatures in computers with hardware monitor chips. SpeedFan can even access S.M.A.R.T. info and show hard disk temperatures. SpeedFan supports SCSI disks too. SpeedFan can even change the FSB on some hardware (but this should be considered a bonus feature). SpeedFan can access digital temperature sensors and can change fan speeds accordingly, thus reducing noise. SpeedFan works fine with Windows 9x, ME, NT, 2000, 2003, XP, Vista, Windows 7, 2008, Windows 8, Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012. It works with Windows 64 bit too.

SpeedFan screen capture:

[image: SpeedFan screen capture]

The SpeedFan icon will also show these temperature if you hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

There are *lots* of programs to monitor your PC’s sensors, many of them are free to use or try. DavidPostill already mentioned SpeedFan, here’s some more:

- [CPUID HWMonitor](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)
- [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/)
- [Open Hardware Monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and [Libre Hardware Monitor](https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor) (fork that is still alive)
- [lm_sensors](https://hwmon.wiki.kernel.org/lm_sensors) (if you’re on Linux)

There’s probably some more that I forgot. Some overclocking utilities also display sensor values.

---

The sensors you want are indeed distinct from the CPU’s internal temperature sensors. Unlike the CPU sensors however, their location is not standardized, they could be anywhere on the mainboard.

From my experience, virtually all mainboards have these sensors. Some have quite a few, others not so many. One thing to look out for is implausible values. Sometimes, unused sensor inputs are not disabled, displaying very high or even sub-zero values. Don’t mind these.